# Detecting raised-event at OS-level (OS Appearance)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, operating-system

I have what seems to be a common problem. I am running Windows 7 Home Premium on one of the most awesomest computers (when it was bought last year) and certain visual effects just automatically turn themselves off.

My average user experience rating is high, so it doesn't explain why this happens. The only feature that ever gets turned off is the 'Show window contents while dragging' option. And it really annoys me.

There are currently no working solutions to this problem online. Other than to "there must be a conflict with another app installed on your machine."

And yes, I do know what app is causing this conflict. It's my bloody Internet Provider's software - you know... that app that you absolutely MUST have open at all times when you're connected to the net.

So, I had a thought. What if I could subscribe to an event so that my app that runs in the background will detect when this 'show window contents while dragging' option is turned off - and then my app will simply turn it back on again.

When I do this manually, it seems to stay in effect for about an hour or two, then it gets switched off again.

Is it possible to handle these types of events, and re-start certain visual effect features? If so, are there any resources on this?

I have not been able to find anything on this sibject yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the [WM_SETTINGSCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message is sent to all windows when a system setting is changed.  Then you can call [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with SPI_GETDRAGFULLWINDOWS to determine if the "Show window contents while dragging" is disabled and use SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS to enable it.

So all that you will need to do is create an application with a form (that can even stay hidden) and override the forms [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) and handle the `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` message and call `SystemParametersInfo` using p/Invoke.  The p/Invoke definition for [SystemParamtersInfo is available at pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SystemParametersInfo.html)

Altough what may be easier is change security on the [HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\DragFullWindows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978609.aspx) registry value so that it can't be changed.